# Spring MVC (Spring roo) Hibernate fixtures

Tags: database, spring, hibernate, model-view-controller, fixtures

I was wondering what is the best approach of adding fixtures in a spring mvc + hibernate application for development purposes. Basically the idea is when the application is loaded in "dev" environment a certain set of fixtures should prepopulate the database. A couple of considerations are that I dont want to use DbUnit or load hard coded sql, instead I want to use the entity manager to generate the fixtures inside of the application, so that i can use certain services when needed to generate the information (lets say i want to create a few users fixtues, id like to be able to use the salt service, etc to generate the passwords and so on). Ideally as well I would like to be able to separate the fixtures in different classes for each domain type. So far I havent been able to find anything helpful in that sense? Id appreciate any help, keep in mind I am a complete Spring newb, coming from a PHP background, so please keep it a bit more detailed as to what should go where :S. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for development right? Not just for unit or integration testing? If so I think I would just create a Java class with a main and put your data creation code in there. You could also make that class auto wired with a data population beans. Then have all your data populators implement the same interface. Make sure your main method is annotated like so:

```
@ContextConfiguration( "classpath:/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml")
```

This will essentially load the spring configuration for your static main method.

Then you can either have the build run it each time after wiping the database or just call it manually when you need to populate data.

If this is just for unit testing then I'd create a data populator in your test source path and then call it from your test #setUp methods.

Consider the following:

```
public interface Populator {
   void run();
}

@Repository
public class UserPopulator {
   @PersistenceContext
   private EntityManager em;

   @Transactional
   public void run() {
      create some users
      em.persist( users );
   }
}


@Repository
public class ThingPopulator {
   @PersistenceContext
   private EntityManager em;

   @Transactional
   public void run() {
      create some thing
      em.persist( thing );
   }
}

@Configurable
@ContextConfiguration( "classpath:/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml")
public class DataPopulator {
   @Autowired
   private List<Populator> populators;

   public void run() {
      for ( Populator populator : populators ) {
         populator.run();
      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      new DataPopulator().run();
   }
}
```

Then you can just run this class for devlopment. If you have a Unit test just for users you can also do:

```
public class UserTest {
   @Before
   public void setUp() {
      new UserPopulator().run();
   }

   // tests
}
```

Or something like that.

Comment: So basically have 2 distinct sets of the same interface having this annotation and classes implementing it for the different fixtures in the main application and in the tests path? Is there any way to share some of it though, so i dont have to maintain 2 versions of it one for tests and one for the app itself. Also in your oppinion whats the best approach for utilizing fixtures in Hibernate/Spring because what i see is mainly based on loading static .sql files and i think thats extremely unflexible...

Comment: Well, I have my application data as entities so I don't need .sql files. I just have the code create and persist entities for populators. And you only need one set. Mark than as @Repostiory and you can use them in tests or in your static main.

Comment: @Feras I edited my answer to give you more concrete direction. I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for, I guess ill just add some tweaks to the populator interface so that in test environment i have a method like cleanup, which will delete the test fixtures that were create during the test or something of that sort. Thanks a lot!